# How to get month name of custom range

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

In my laravel application,
The input is like this:

```
$from_year = 2019;
$from_month = 10;

$to_year = 2020;
$to_month = 4;
```

The expected output:

```
months = [
'October 2019', 'November 2019', 'December 2019', 'January 2020', 'February 2020', 'March 2020', 'April 2020'
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$startDate = date($from_year.'-'.$from_month.'-01');
$diff = (($to_year - $from_year) * 12) + ($to_month - $from_month);

$months = [];
for($i=0;$i<=$diff;$i++) {
    $months[] = date('F Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' month', strtotime($startDate)));
}
```

simple code with `date()` function

Answer (score 2):

You could use couple methods that uses `DateTime`. First of all, you could create current and end date (with 1st day of the month) objects, and then calculate month difference using `date_diff`. Then it's just simple for with adding month interval.

Vanilla PHP solution would look like this:

```php
$from_year = 2019;
$from_month = 10;

$to_year = 2020;
$to_month = 4;

$date = new DateTime("$from_year-$from_month-01");
$diff = date_diff($date, new DateTime("$to_year-$to_month-01"));
$monthsDiff = $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m;
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$monthsArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= $monthsDiff; $i++){
    $monthsArray[] = $date->format('F Y');
    $date->add($interval);
}
```

Also, as you can see, I'm using the `format` method on `DateTime` object. More about the method you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
   <?php

$from_year = 2019;
$from_month = 10;

$to_year = 2020;
$to_month = 4;
$arr = [];
for($i=$from_year;$i<$to_year;$i++) {
    
    if($i==$from_year){
        $fmonth = $from_month;
    }else{
        $fmonth = 1;
    }
    for($j=$fmonth;$j<=12;$j++){
        array_push($arr,DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $j)->format('F'). " ".$i);
    }
}
    for($i=1;$i<=$to_month;$i++){
        array_push($arr,DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i)->format('F'). " ".$to_year);
    }

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and CarbonPeriod libraries.

Here is how it goes:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$from_year = 2019;
$from_month = 10;

$to_year = 2020;
$to_month = 4;

$fromDate = new Carbon('1-' . $from_month . '-' . $from_year);
$toDate = new Carbon('1-' . $to_month . '-' . $to_year);

$differnces = CarbonPeriod::create($fromDate, '1 month', $toDate);

$differenceInDates = [];

foreach ($differnces as $differnce) {
    $differenceInDates[] = $differnce->format("M F");
}
```

This will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_year = 2019;
$from_month = 10;

$to_year = 2020;
$to_month = 4;

$start = strtotime($from_year . "-" . $from_month . "-01");
$end = strtotime($to_year . "-" . $to_month . "-01");
$months = [date("F Y",$start)];

while(strtotime(end($months)) < $end){
    $months[] = date("F Y",strtotime(end($months) . " +1 month"));
}
```